# Connecting an Android application to sql server through sql server express

Tags: android, sql-server

I've been looking for a way to connect an Android application to a SQL server. Tried different codes and asked many programmers. Didn't get anywhere. It seems that the problem is in the connection url.

The application I got to make involves creating some sql tables. For instance, at the beggining it needs to veriffy login data given by a user against that data in one of those tables.
In addition to Android studio, I was guided to install and use SQL server express (nothing else).

Using SQL server express 2008 R2 I created a database on my computer and a table. The connection to the server didn't work. The codes I found always involved a password and a username for the connection. Is that mandatory? I didn't get a username for the connection when I installed the server. It involved getting an instance name and a password.

I searched for information on the connection url's parameters in order to fix the url I got. Couldn't find what I need to change.

I found a code thoguh which one can define a password and a usename:

```
private Connection conn;

    public MySQLConnection() throws SQLException {

        System.out.println("At MySQLConnection()");

        String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("user","fred");
            props.setProperty("password","secret");
            props.setProperty("ssl","true");

            String url = "jdbc:mysql://zivpc/workers?user=fred&password=secret&ssl=true";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            System.out.println("connected");


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Trying to connect results in the following exception: `CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`.

Thanks!

Comment: First, JDBC is not designed for use with mobile devices, where connections might get dropped at random points, Please reconsider what you are doing. Beyond that, your code is for MySQL. MySQL is not SQL Server.

Comment: The assignment I got involved connecting an android application to sql database through sql server express. Is there a proper way to do that, for instance, with something other than jdbc?

Comment: The typical way to communicate to a server from a mobile client is through a Web service. The Web service talks to the database; the Android or iOS app talks to the Web service.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an API (REST, etc.) running on a web server, with that web server having access to the firewalled-off database server. And authentication for your API so that you don't have random people DDoSing your service and database.

Your database server should not be exposed to the internet at all, nor directly accessible from your client. Nor should you be sending SQL queries directly from the client through to the database server. Your API exposes a set of functionality and is very restrictive about what the client can request and receive.

Mobile app -> internet -> web server -> firewall -> SQL Server

The details of "how do I implement this" far exceed the scope of Stack Overflow. There are numerous tutorials and walkthroughs available online. Choose wisely.

Additional note: You say you're using SQL Server 2008R2 Express Edition. Be advised that this version of SQL Server will be EOL in less than three months. No one should have been doing new development on it for the past 5 years. Be careful taking advice from whoever "guided" you to install this version in 2019.

Comment: Thanks. I wish to avoid wasting time and effort as mush as possible, so in I'd like to know if in your opinion, the tutorial in the following link is useful for adding a web service to an adroid applicaion, to be used for connecting a sql server:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTO5a1IeBl8